# RoR dual foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user table and a request table.  The user table contains employees and clients.  I have added user_id and employee_id to the request table.

I thought the following would allow me to have both foreign keys point to the user table:

```
belongs_to :user          # foreign_key "user_id"
belongs_to :employee, :class_name => "user", :foreign_key => "employee_id" #   foreign_key "employee_id"
```

But, I get "uninitialized constant request::user" from this form line:

```
    <%= f.association :employee, :label_method => :full_name, :label => 'Assigned To' %>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `:class_name => "User"` instead of `:class_name => "user"`?

Comment: Thank you - it's always the little things!!

Comment: The Devil is in the details :P